# objective c class with dynamic variable syntax - warning issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simeple class that represents a MODEL

myModel.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prop1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prop2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) myModel2 * model;
```

myModel.m

```
@dynamic prop1;
@dynamic prop2;
@dynamic model;
```

myModel2.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prop1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prop2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) myModel  * model;
```

myModel2.m

```
@dynamic prop1;
@dynamic prop2;
@dynamic model;
```

someclass.m

```
myModel *myVar = (code that populates);

[myVar setProp1:@"test"];  // I get a myVar may not respond to -setprop1;
[myVar setProp2:@"test"]; // NO Warning everything oK.
```

Also, the models contain circular references...

Answer (score 1):

The convention is setProp1:, not setprop1:

Not sure why you're not seeing a warning on the second one. BTW, your property is an NSNumber* and you are trying to pass an int there.

Comment: even though my declaration is in lowercase?

Comment: yes, the setter for a property called 'prop1' is 'setProp1' according to convention. If you don't tell the compiler otherwise, that is what it will expect.

Comment: ok well it still complains. I have like 6 properties all declared the same way and only a few of them are ok while the other have warnings about not responding...

Comment: well, are they literally 'prop1' and 'prop2' or did you change the actual names when posting the question?

Comment: i just changed the name for the post. but they are just a name change.

Comment: The edited version of your code in your question is correct. Of course you have to provide the implementation of the setters at runtime, but the compiler will trust you on that. that's not the cause for a warning. Your actual code must have a mistake in it.

Comment: would my circular reference cause any problems?  see updated code above. my model.h reference model2.h and model2.h references model.h

Comment: the strange thing is that one property is ok and the other gives a warning when ther are both declared the same

Comment: No, those references are not a problem. Do you have warnings in either of those headers?

Comment: No. Warning only show up in the class that is instantiating the models

Comment: OK, all I can tell you is that what you have posted is correct. So in editing your code before posting, you fixed the problem. So find someone you trust to look at your actual code and you should be able to find the actual issue. Good luck.

Comment: I also noticed another thing. my variable name is theModels... and the warning message reads "Models may not respond... what happen to the word "the"

Comment: scrath that last comment.lol i am confusing myself.. but problem still exists